# How to update facebook's og tags

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, web

I've been over this for days and I know this has been asked a lot but I still couldn't find an answer.

I have a blog-like website, which has posts, and each post needs to have its title and description on the facebook article. I can set up the those like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
```

But since facebook only reads and caches the first time this is defined, it doesn't allow me to change it dynamically.

So I need to have a diffrent title/description/image for each post, and I can't do that defining them with og tags, how can I do it?

This seems like something really easy to accomplish, I must be missing something really obvious, help please?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems Facebook is updating that information every couple days, and there's no way to do it dynamically. However, you can do it manually by using the Sharing Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

You can scrape the site again every time there's an update. I don't believe there's an API for that though.

Comment: I've been using that to test it, but what I need is to have diffrent titles, descriptions, iamges, etc for each post

Comment: Gotcha. Do you have an og tag on the permalinks of the posts? You can add a tag on every page you want, and that will work dynamically. If you define different tags on different pages and test that, the Sharing debugger should show the correct ones to you.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a page for every post, they're all in the same page, and I just add .../#anchor1, .../#anchor2 on each link. Much like when we share a StackOverflow answer

Comment: Meta/og tags are specific to a single html document, so you won't be able to add different ones for sections (/#anchor1, /#anchor2) of the page. May I ask what CMS/generator you are using for the blog?

Comment: I'm not using any CMS, I have a template for the posts, and each time I publish a new one I just paste it and change the text and ID's

Comment: I see. I would suggest you look into static site generators like [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/). If you don't want to do that you should create a new file/document for every post and not just add it to the same document, since facebook bots and also search engines will think that it's only one page and not multiple posts.

Comment: Won't that become a bit heavy with time? If I ever hit 1k posts, I would have 1k extra files. Is that advisable?

Comment: Not at all advisable, but you also don't want to copy and paste 1k posts, and change the IDs of every singe one, right? Then you would have one huge index.html file with 1k posts. That's why you should look into using a cms, or probably better, a static site generator like Jekyll. It does all that work for you and the og tags would work as well.

Comment: Actually I copied and pasted a thousand posts to test it, and it loaded instantly, and changing the ID's with Sublime Text is really easy I jsut need to change one and it changes them all. But this still doesn't feel good, I'm going to look into CMS's and Jekyll

Answer (score 0):

You can update it with a simple API call, this is explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update

You should not do that too often though, og tags get locked in after a while. They are not meant to be used for dynamic content.

About dynamically changing OG tags on a button click (= with JavaScript): That is not possible at all. Each shared URL must have its own permalink, and the Facebook crawler does not run JavaScript. Also, fragments are not part of the URL, you cannot use them either.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it well, I edited it now. What I need is to have a diffrent title/description/etc for each post. If that isn't possible, what I meant with update was to update those values when the "share" button is clicked on a post